# Difference between activities context

Tags: android, android-context

I am new in Android development and I have question about Context. Is it matter what context I use to start new activity? Suppose there are three activities in my android application, for example aActivity, bActivity and cActivity. aActvity is the main. bActivity started on button click from aActivity by code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, bActivity.class); 
startActivity (intent);
```

cActivity started on button click from bActivity by code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(someContext, cActivity.class); 
startActivity (intent);
```

What is the difference for my app if in bActivity someContext will be context of aActivity but not context of bActivity?

Answer (score 0):

Each activity if you will go deeper is subclass of `Context`. Also context of activity proxing all method to `baseContext`. Base context is the application context of your app.

> Is it matter what context I use to start new activity?

It is doesn't matter which context you are using, for launching new activity.

Answer (score 0):

Different types of contexts are used differently.There are those that are tied to the lifecycle of an activity and those tied to the lifecycle of the application.Context accesses the current state of application or object by invoking either `getApplicationContext()` `getContext()` `getBaseContext()` or `this` when in a class that is extending from context such as the application, activity, service and IntentServiceClasses.
So for your case ;You can start an activity from any activity using any context so long as the context reference does not hold beyond the lifecycle of that component(activity you are starting the next activity from)..
You can get more reading [here](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-context-in-android-application-330913e32514)

Comment: Dose it mean that if I store context of some activity in static variable and than use this context to start any new activity which is not at the same Task (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) then I obtain memory leak?

Comment: Yes you get a memory leak and also declaring android contexts static gives you this error message:Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak and also breaks Instant Run.